# How to troubleshoot/fix Azure Function host crashing?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

Azure portal displays that my azure function is up and running, but when I navigate to `https://{functionapp-name}.azurewebsites.net` via browser I'm getting

> "Function host is not running."

But I definetly can see that processing happening sometimes by observing

`{functionapp-name}/LogFiles/Application/Functions/Host/*.log file.`

Any suggestions on troubleshooting this?

Comment: Have you tried setting up Application Insights?

Comment: @MaGu Any progress? Feel free to ask if you are still trapped.

Comment: @JerryLiu Thanks, it turns out I have several issues at the same moment, this one case was related to missed "vesrion": "2.0" host.json. But I was mostly concerned about siutation when host process crashes unexpectedly - in such cases there are no any entries in host log (well sometimes in the past I have seen OutOfMemory exception). Also I can see that CPU Usage and Memory utilizes at almost 100% - so I guess it's the reason. I just wondered why I can't see it in log reliably. Would be interesting to know about how to profile it - locally it uses 80MB at most - with short test period.

Comment: @Thomas No, we haven't setup App Insight for Azure Functions. Does it provide more telemetry information out of the box than usual log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether `Function host is not running` is consistent after restarting Function app. And make sure we checked the latest logs.

Basically if our function host fails to start, we can see details in Host log and functions won't process unless error is fixed.

For a successfully started function host, we can see logs like

```
Host initialized
Host started
Job host started
Host lock lease acquired by instance ID 'xx'.
```

If those pleasant information without error is all we got, and functions are triggered as expected, there's nothing to worry about.

Once there're some mistakes(e.g. in [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#sample-hostjson-file) and [proxies.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#advanced-configuration) settings) stop host starting, error is shown as below. Just try to fix according to official samples.

```
A host error has occurred
xxx //some error details
Stopping JobHost
Job host stopped
```